# Why should I use PostGIS functions?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

Is there a reason for using PostGIS functions such as `ST_Area` and `ST_Length` when there are already functions/operators for doing the same thing in PostgreSQL (`area` and `@-@`)

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223487/what-is-the-purpose-of-postgis-on-postgresql

Comment: if you only need the functions included in Postgres you can avoid having to add the postgis extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the linked answer is good.

But to clarify.

The standard PostgreSQL spatial functions work on the PostgreSQL geometric types. While the PostGIS ones work on the PostGIS geometry types.

PostgreSQL offers a few functions to deal with spatial operators:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-geometry.html

It does not offer the full set that PostGIS does:

https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html

So if you will ever need a function that is not supported by PostgreSQL, you should go with the PostGIS geometry type, which allows for more spatial functionality.